# How can I call a pact module on chain using passed in module+defun name

Tags: pact-lang

I have a contract that is able to call another module on chain from within itself, and it is working as follows:

```
(defun call-other(nft-id)
    (mod-2.defun-name ...params)
```

I am trying to do it dynamically by passing module name of "mod-2" to the defun, and hopefully using a symbol to call mod-2 dynamically but it cant resolve mod.

Ideal:

```
(defun call-other(nft-id:string mod:string)

  ('mod.defun-name ...params )
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can pass modules as params and call them as follows :

(From [Babena marm implementations](https://github.com/babena-art/babena-art/blob/main/pact/ledger.pact); awesome job folks and thanks!)

[calling from defun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Zla.png)

[passing through env-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIKu4.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).